# Transparent Objects get blown out when rendered but is fine in viewport

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, particles, transparency

I’m working on a scene right now with a vine and leaves. The leaves are made with a plane and an alpha image of a leaf. It was initially made using the leaves as a particle system but when I would render the leaves get huge and the scale got messed up and the transparent parts show up black too. I have blending mode set to Alpha Clip and displacement to bump only.
Once that didn’t work I tried applying the particle system and all the transforms and that hasn’t worked either same issue. It looks fine in the viewport display rendered view so it must be something missing in the render settings. I'm using Cycles. I attached the render, the viewport display, and the shading settings as an image, Any help is greatly appreciated!
[image: Leaf Texture Nodes][image][image]

Comment: Did you check for hidden objects? Alt+h

Comment: Check the modifiers on the plane object. It's possible that there are different subdiv levels or a solidify that's toggled off for render. Not sure why alpha could be missing, but Viewport Display settings (blending mode etc) don't matter for Cycles at all.

Comment: That worked @Vagabonk , looks like the leaves were hidden from a previous version. Thank you so much! Its an obvious solution that I overlooked, still not sure why it gave me that result, but at least it worked out. :)